# C# Winforms - My application is printing off two numbers but I only want to print off one

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm make a "programming language", and I can set variables like strings, and integers, and I can print them off and I'm currently working on adding them, this is the code to add:

```
if (line.Contains("%"))
{
    string name1 = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('%') + 1).Split('+')[0];
    string name2 = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('+') + 1).Split(';')[0];

    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in integers)
    {
       if (name1 == kvp.Key)
       {
           value1 = kvp.Value;
       }

       if (name2 == kvp.Key)
       {
           value2 = kvp.Value;
       }

       int answer = value1 + value2;

       Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }
}
```

This is how the code is supposed to work:

`&num1=1; 
 &num2=2;
 %num1+num2;`

The out come is:

`1 
 3`

The code works, but Its printing off the value of value1, and I think its because the variable, value2, is 0 and its adding 1 + 0 then it sets it then adds 1 + 2, but that doesn't make much sense to me, so I really don't know what's wrong with it.

BTW: & is for integers, $ is for strings.

Comment: Why don't you use the Int.TryParse function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `Console.WriteLine` is inside you're loop. Change it to below to address that issue:

```
int answer = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in integers)
{
   if (name1 == kvp.Key)
   {
       value1 = kvp.Value;
   }

   if (name2 == kvp.Key)
   {
       value2 = kvp.Value;
   }

   answer = value1 + value2;           
}
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!